# Is there an equivalent of $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist and $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist for Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Is there an equivalent of  **$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist** and **$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlBlacklist** for Angular2?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider

Comment: Did you find out in the meanwhile?

Comment: @StephanKristyn not yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is! In Angular2 you import and use `SafeResourceUrl` and `DomSanitizationService` as described in my blog:

http://meshfields.de/embed-youtube-videos-ionic2-angular2/